# Guessing the cross terms in a metric ansatz

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor

Let's say I want to write down a metric ansatz for some spacetime manifold. How do I know if there are cross terms or where they might be? For example, if I were to try and derive the ansatz for the Kerr metric, how do I logically deduce that there is a cross terms in the $dtd\phi$ terms?

Comment: I don't think you can. Surely the whole point of an ansatz is to guess the starting equation and put it into the field equations to see if it works. You would have to try it with and without cross terms and see what happened.

Comment: Generally speaking the method to guess if there are no crossterms is to find out if there's a reflection symmetry, ie if the metric is invariant under $t \to -t$